# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

It seems like this error message has been posted a lot, but I have not been able to come up with the proper answer.

I am following [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-google-places-integration/) tutorial and I can't get the Google Places Info to show up on my screen. I was looking at the LogCat and saw this:

```
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 127: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.6997688,-86.2406069&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery&key=AIzaSyDdMnQpqT9pr-k6VhwesT1OBAg_qkvflxU
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at com.mbau.miniproject2.ShowMapActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(ShowMapActivity.java:145)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at com.mbau.miniproject2.ShowMapActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(ShowMapActivity.java:1)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-20 02:01:32.278: W/System.err(19832):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at com.mbau.miniproject2.ShowMapActivity$GetPlaces.onPostExecute(ShowMapActivity.java:187)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at com.mbau.miniproject2.ShowMapActivity$GetPlaces.onPostExecute(ShowMapActivity.java:1)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
09-20 02:01:32.388: W/System.err(19832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code I have is literally the EXACT same as provided in the tutorial, with the exception of my Google API key in the URL, my Maps key in the manifest, and my main activity is called ShowMapActivity.

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but I think it has something to do with the URL, which produces the first error.

At the same time, I can't see any invalid character in the URL, and when I copy/paste the URL from LogCat into my browser, it returns a nice JSON file.

Any thoughts/possible fixes?

Thanks.

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s30kgdt6srtaspz/MiniProject2.zip) to my files

Comment: What's at line 187 in your code? The source you reference is only ~155 lines.

Comment: Added my code via a dropbox .zip file
line 187 in my code is:
places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
//marker options for each place returned

Comment: @Jon To clarify more: line 187 instantiates the MarkerOptions array created with the length of the returned “results” array.

Comment: @pratik https://www.dropbox.com/s/s30kgdt6srtaspz/MiniProject2.zip

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So I ended up changing my code from:

```
    String placesSearchStr="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/"
    +"json?location="
    +String.valueOf(lat)
    +","
    +String.valueOf(lng)
    +"&radius=5000&sensor=true"
    +"&types=food|bar|church|museum|art_gallery"
    +"&key=AIzaSyDdMnQpqT9pr-k6VhwesT1OBAg_qkvflxU";
```

to:

```
String latVal=String.valueOf(lat);
String lngVal=String.valueOf(lng);
String url;
try {
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
        +URLEncoder.encode(latVal, "UTF-8")
        +","
        +URLEncoder.encode(lngVal, "UTF-8")
        +"&radius="
        +URLEncoder.encode("5000", "UTF-8")
        +"&sensor="
        +URLEncoder.encode("true", "UTF-8")
        +"&types="
        +URLEncoder.encode("food|bar|church|museum|art_gallery", "UTF-8")
        +"&key="
        +URLEncoder.encode("AIzaSyDdMnQpqT9pr-k6VhwesT1OBAg_qkvflxU", "UTF-8");
        new GetPlaces().execute(url);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this solved my problem.

Comment: ahah, I knew it had to be something along those lines. Now I remember someone saying it was a good habit to use "UTF-8", but I've never ran into any issues before that actually required it. 

Thanks for following up & I've updated my answer with a slightly easier way to set the formatting.

Comment: is this working if +12.4242,-98.1739|+12.4298,-98.1739

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.valueOf()` when adding the lat & long. It may be leaving extra stuff in there that's causing you trouble when trying to parse it that is getting cut out when the string is being displayed.

```
String placesSearchStr = new String(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/"
    +"json?location="
    +String.valueOf(lat)
    +","
    +String.valueOf(lng)
    +"&radius=5000&sensor=true"
    +"&types=food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery"
    +"&key=AIzaSyDdMnQpqT9pr-k6VhwesT1OBAg_qkvflxU"
    ,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately that didn't work. Still getting identical LogCat errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a Java library that handles these HTTP details for you and allows you to interact with the Google Places API through Java methods and objects, you can try [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets) (disclosure: I'm the developer).

I'm also working on an Android library project that will include Loaders, Adapters, and widgets for use with the Google Places API.

Note that when using Sprockets in Android, you will most likely want to use ProGuard for release builds to strip out the unused code in the dependency libraries (see the POM for dependencies).