# Fail in Android using PHP with MySQL query

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have one activity with a listview with some towns of Málaga (Spain). I fill the list with a MySQL query using PHP and JSON. The towns have special character (like Málaga). When I click on one option of the list I call other activity which do a query to a database. I pass in the url the value of the selected item in the list for filter the query. The problem is when I execute the query. If I select one town without special characters all it's right but if I select one with special character I have the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query`. I try to pass the variable in my web browser and it works.
Why have I the error?

This is the code of the second activity

```
public class Partidos2 extends Activity {
private String result=null;
private InputStream is=null;
private StringBuilder sb=null; 
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
Bundle bundle;
String localidad;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_partidos2);
    bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    new async().execute();

}
class async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(Partidos2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String...params){
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://proyectoabel.tk/android/partidos.php?localidad="+bundle.getString("localidad"));
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
            is=entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Conexion: ",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexión fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try{
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb=new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine()+"\n");
            String line="0";
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            return result;
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
            return result;
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{
            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);
            TableLayout tv=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int contador=1;
            for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length()-1;i++){
                TableRow tr=new TableRow(Partidos2.this);
                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                if(contador==1){
                    TextView ea=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    ea.setText("Local");
                    ea.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    ea.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ea.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(ea);
                    TextView eb=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    eb.setText("Visitante");
                    eb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    eb.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    eb.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(eb);
                    TextView fe=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    fe.setText("Fecha");
                    fe.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    fe.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    fe.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(fe);
                    TextView ho=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    ho.setText("Hora");
                    ho.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    ho.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ho.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(ho);
                    TextView ca=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    ca.setText("Cat.");
                    ca.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    ca.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ca.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(ca);
                    TextView pi=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    pi.setText("Pista");
                    pi.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    pi.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    pi.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tr.addView(pi);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline=new View(Partidos2.this);
                    vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 2));
                    vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline);
                    contador=0;
                }
                else{
                    JSONObject json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    TextView b=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("EquipoA"));
                    b.setText(stime);
                    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    tr.addView(b);
                    TextView b1=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime1=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("EquipoB"));
                    b1.setText(stime1);
                    b1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b1.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    tr.addView(b1);
                    TextView b2=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime2=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Fecha"));
                    b2.setText(stime2);
                    b2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b2.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    tr.addView(b2);
                    TextView b3=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime3=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Hora"));
                    b3.setText(stime3);
                    b3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b3.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    tr.addView(b3);
                    TextView b4=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime4=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Abreviatura"));
                    b4.setText(stime4);
                    b4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b4.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
                    tr.addView(b4);
                    TextView b5=new TextView(Partidos2.this);
                    String stime5=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Pista"));
                    b5.setText(stime5);
                    b5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    b5.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tr.addView(b5);
                    tv.addView(tr);
                    final View vline1=new View(Partidos2.this);
                    vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
                    vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.addView(vline1);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        } catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error: ", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the code of the PHP script.

```
$localidad=$_GET["localidad"];
include"../conexion.php";
$mysqli=new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);    
$mysqli->set_charset("latin1");
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    echo "Error nยบ ".$conexion->connect_errno.": ".$conexion->connect_error;
}
if($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT E1.Nombre EquipoA, E2.Nombre EquipoB, DATE_FORMAT(Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') Fecha, TIME_FORMAT(Hora, '%H:%i') Hora, Abreviatura, PA.Nombre Pista
FROM PARTIDO P INNER JOIN EQUIPO E1 ON P.EquipoA=E1.Codigo_equipo 
INNER JOIN EQUIPO E2 ON P.EquipoB=E2.Codigo_equipo 
INNER JOIN PABELLON PA ON P.Codigo_pabellon=PA.Codigo_pabellon 
INNER JOIN CATEGORIA ON P.Codigo_categoria=CATEGORIA.Codigo_categoria
INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD ON PA.Codigo_localidad=LOCALIDAD.Codigo_localidad
WHERE Jornada=(SELECT valor FROM CONFIGURACION WHERE descripcion='jornada') AND LOCALIDAD.Nombre='$localidad' ORDER BY Fecha, Hora")){
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
        $resultado[]=$row;
    }
        print(json_encode($resultado));
}
else{
    print(json_encode($mysqli->error));
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Try this String localidad= bundle.getString("localidad"); URLEncoder.encode(localidad, "UTF-8") Hope it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910187/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-character-in-query

Comment: I use it but I have the same error

Comment: I follow the link you send me and now the error is other `org.JSON.JSONException: Value AlhaurÃ-n of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray` (The value I pass is Alhaurín)

Comment: I think IllegalArgumentException issues solved now you are getting error in JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);

Comment: Yes now it's other error. The first is solved.

Comment: Change the below code to php script $localidad=urldecode($_GET["localidad"]);