# Get method with header parameter not working android

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "category": [{
    "id": "90",
    "user_id": "1",
    "category_id": "27",
    "name": "આણંદ કોમર્સિયલ લેયર",
    "order": "0",
    "created_at": "2014-05-03 17:09:54",
    "updated_at": "2014-05-03 17:09:54",
    "deleted": "0",
    "subtopics": [{
      "id": "203",
      "user_id": "1",
      "category_id": "27",
      "subcategory_id": "90",
      "name": "આણંદ કોમર્સિયલ લેયર (સંકર જાત)",
      "order": "0",
      "details": "&lt;p style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"\" src=\"/packages/wysiwyg/ckeditor/plugins/kcfinder/upload/images/1.png\" style=\"height:271px; width:237px\" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;ul&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;પ્રથમ ઈંડું મુક્વાની સરેરાશ ઉંમર:૧૪૨ દિવસ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સરેરાશ વાર્ષિક ઈંડા ઉત્પાદન : ૩૦૦ ઈંડા&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૪૦ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૨ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૭૨ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૪ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સારી જીવાદોરી&lt;/li&gt;\r\n&lt;/ul&gt;\r\n",
      "mobile_detail": "&lt;p style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"\" src=\"/packages/wysiwyg/ckeditor/plugins/kcfinder/upload/images/1.png\" style=\"height:271px; width:237px\" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;ul&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;પ્રથમ ઈંડું મુક્વાની સરેરાશ ઉંમર:૧૪૨ દિવસ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સરેરાશ વાર્ષિક ઈંડા ઉત્પાદન : ૩૦૦ ઈંડા&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૪૦ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૨ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૭૨ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૪ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સારી જીવાદોરી&lt;/li&gt;\r\n&lt;/ul&gt;\r\n",
      "created_at": "2014-05-03 17:11:43",
      "updated_at": "2014-05-11 13:41:31",
      "deleted": "0",
      "images": [],
      "videos": []
    }]
  }]
}
```

I have the following code:

```java
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    InputStream is=null;
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httpPost.setHeader("Mobile-Tokon", "7c^4N:9Y*Tq;P^f");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String json="";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8000);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    JSONObject jObj=null;
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        Log.d("JSON",jObj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

In my Java class, I call the above function like this:

```
getJSONFromUrl("http://ikishan.192.168.1.87.xip.io/api/newapps/27?email=api.ikisan@aau.in&password=%~?7ON9Xjp;BcYu");
```

I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence: %~? in query at index 83: http://ikishan.192.168.1.87.xip.io/api/newapps/27?email=api.ikisan@aau.in&password=%~?7ON9Xjp;BcYu

At this line:

```
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: you should try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18923626/3117966) solution

Comment: this url which you pass is dynamically created? your password encode in which format?

Comment: you have to pass encoded url . you can encode  url using  which class i had  post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. if you encrypct password then you can do like below .

```
// Encrypt Password to UTF-8 format

private String encrypt(String pwd) {
    String encryptedPwd = null;
    try {
        byte[] byteArray = pwd.getBytes("UTF-8");
        encryptedPwd = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedPwd;
}
```

you can Encode URL with below class

```
public class EncodingUtil{


 /**
 * Decodes the passed UTF-8 String using an algorithm that's compatible with
 * JavaScript's <code>decodeURIComponent</code> function. Returns
 * <code>null</code> if the String is <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param s The UTF-8 encoded String to be decoded
 * @return the decoded String
 */
public static String decodeURIComponent(String s)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String result = null;

    try
    {
        result = URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8");
    }

    // This exception should never occur.
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        result = s;
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Encodes the passed String as UTF-8 using an algorithm that's compatible
 * with JavaScript's <code>encodeURIComponent</code> function. Returns
 * <code>null</code> if the String is <code>null</code>.
 *
 * @param s The String to be encoded
 * @return the encoded String
 */
public static String encodeURIComponent(String s)
{
    String result = null;

    try
    {
        result = URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8")
                .replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
                .replaceAll("\\%21", "!")
                .replaceAll("\\%27", "'")
                .replaceAll("\\%28", "(")
                .replaceAll("\\%29", ")")
                .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~");
    }

    // This exception should never occur.
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        result = s;
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Private constructor to prevent this class from being instantiated.
 */
private EncodingUtil()
{
    super();
}}
```

Comment: Android Developer : your code is working but how can i decode mobile_detail tag value in my android application

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya which MobileDetail Tag??

Comment: Android Developer: ya see my json there are     "mobile_detail": "&lt;p style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"\" ...... which include gujarati font with html content

Comment: try like this  Html.fromHtml(String).toString();

Comment: Android Developer : i try you code but when i put this i text alignment making irregular  and some gujarati fonts is not wraping properly  see my edit question i post image with output

Comment: Android Developer:  it is not nested dear if i post it new one than it is duplicate question so i put in in edit portion

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya dear its about how to decode html text in android. its not same question

Comment: Android Developer  Ok fine you have idea pls. share

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya but what problem you get in output i didnt get .everything display perfect. can you post image for  what exactly you want

Comment: Android Developer : see my screenshots at line no 4 at right side text is cutting means whole text is not wraping perfect

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya it may b text view padding problem or it may be you didnt get proper html from web response

Comment: Android Developer :Ok Thanks for your time  and efforts

Answer (score 2):

That's because the URL that you've mentioned is not a valid URL as specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571518/2815219) SO answer.

> **a complete URL is always in its encoded form**: you take the strings for
>   the individual components (scheme, authority, path, etc.), encode each
>   according to its own rules, and then combine them into the complete
>   URL string. **Trying to build a complete unencoded URL string and then**
>   **encode it separately leads to subtle bugs,** like spaces in the path
>   being incorrectly changed to plus signs (which an RFC-compliant server
>   will interpret as real plus signs, not encoded spaces).

Those invalid characters that are mentioned in `IllegalArgumentException` exception should not be directly sent with `GET` request and needs to be converted into this format

```
Character   From Windows-1252   From UTF-8
  %               %25               %25
  ~               %7E               %7E
  ?               %3F               %3F
```

see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) url for complete list

---

In Java, the correct way to build a URL is with the URI class.

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class HelloWorld {
    static String uri = "http://ikishan.192.168.1.87.xip.io/api/newapps/27";
    static String params = "?email=api.ikisan@aau.in&password=%~?7ON9Xjp;BcYu";

     public static void main(String []args){
        try {
            String encodedParams = URLEncoder.encode( params, "ASCII" ).toString();
            System.out.println(uri + encodedParams);
        }
        catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            //do something
        }
     }
}
```

**Output**

```
http://ikishan.192.168.1.87.xip.io/api/newapps/27%3Femail%3Dapi.ikisan%40aau.in%26password%3D%25%7E%3F7ON9Xjp%3BBcYu
```